# Why the point of tangency is lower than the point where the line crosses OY

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, parametric

I'm trying to find such $a$ so the system has 3 positive solutions:
$$3x^2-24x+64=a|x-3|$$
The right answer is $6+2\sqrt{57}; (21\frac13; +\infty )$.

I made a graph and figured out that $a>21\frac13$. The next step was to find where the left side of module function would be a tangent to the parabola. $a=6+2\sqrt{57}$ there. $6+2\sqrt{57} < 21\frac13$. That means that the line with $a=21\frac13$ rises more rapidly.

What I don't understand is why it necessary means that the point of tangency is lower than $(0;64)$ where $a=21\frac13$. (Because if that is true, $x>0$).

I've just started learning to solve problems with parameter. Maybe there's some simple property of function I don't know. Please explain this detail.

Comment: The line $y=a(3-x)$ always passes through $(3,0)$ which is below the parabola. When $a=\frac{64}{3}$, the line $y=a(3-x)$ and the parabola has two intersection points in $0\le x\lt 3$ (one of them is $(0,64)$). Since the $x$-coordinate of the vertex of the parabola is $4$ which is larger than $3$, the parabola, which is convex downward, is decreasing in $0\lt x\lt 3$. It follows that the $y$-coordinate of the tangent point is smaller than $64$.

Comment: @mathlove Thank you very much, it got clear! But how do we know that the line and the parabola have two intersection points when $a=\frac{64}{3}$? I put a in the initial equation and got $x=0$ and $x=\frac{8}{9}$. Is it the only way?

Comment: I don't know if it is the only way, but the way is easy since we already know that the equation $3x^2-24x+64=\frac{64}{3}(3-x)$ has a solution $x=0$.

Comment: There is another way using calculus. Let $f(x):=3x^2-24x+64$. Also, let $t$ be the $x$-coordinate of the tangent point. Then, it follows from $f'(0)=-24=-(6+2\sqrt{81})\lt -(6+2\sqrt{57})=f'(t)$ that the $y$-coordinate of the tangent point is smaller than $64$.